# Android Import changes with flavor, even with same folder structure

Tags: android, android-productflavors, android-flavors

My app has two flavors `core` and `foss`, default flavor is core.

I've got 3 subfolders in my src folder, `core`, `foss` and `main`.

I'm trying to access my Home Screen which is referenced in the MainActivity and located in the `main` folder. The HomeScreen itself needs a HomeViewModel and that is contained in both the `core` and `foss` folder, but not in the `main` folder.
[image]

The odd thing for me is when I try to build the `core` flavor it accepts this as a valid import in the Home.kt file:

```
import viewmodels.HomeViewModel
```

In `foss` flavor it only accepts this import:

```
import com.blazecode.tsviewer.viewmodels.HomeViewModel
```

For my understanding these imports are essentially the same, but I have to change it every time I want to switch the flavor.

This is how I declared my flavors:

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    core {
        dimension "version"
        versionNameSuffix "-core"
    }
    foss {
        dimension "version"
        versionNameSuffix "-foss"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    core {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/core/java']
    }
    foss {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/foss/java']
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can move files around or more ideally have one general import so that I don't have to manually change things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue,
the file's package declaration was different.

My core flavor file had this package declaration:

```
package viewmodels
```

While the foss flavor one had this:

```
package com.blazecode.tsviewer.viewmodels
```

I changed both to `package viewmodels` and now it's working!

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants will refer you to the correct way to build flavors.  You can have the different variants point to different folders will still keeping the package structure consistent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated my question and attached my gradle setup for the flavors

Comment: You can set up different directories depending on the flavor

Comment: I added the way I declared the source sets to the question, I still cannot get it to work

Comment: @BlazeCodeDev what error are you seeing?  You build.gradle looks correct

Comment: `Unresolved reference: HomeViewModel`

This is what I'm getting when switching from `codeDebug` to `fossDebug`, so when selected `coreDebug` the import `import viewmodels.HomeViewModel` is fine, in `fossDebug` it only accepts `import com.blazecode.tsviewer.viewmodels.HomeViewModel`

Comment: You need to have HomeViewModel in each set of files with the same package set.  Can you show me what in in your directories?

Comment: I put a screenshot of the directories in the question, is that sufficient?

Comment: Where is your foss, core asnd main directories?

Comment: Both under app/src https://imgur.com/a/Zw2wI5y

Comment: i need to see those directories expanded

Comment: Expanded: https://imgur.com/a/jjoyNRp

Alternatively: https://github.com/BlazeCodeDev/TSViewer/tree/development/app/src